# Как определить что данные из формы были отправлены со страницы?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

На сайте есть POST-форма, которая должна быть отправлена либо при клике на кнопку отправки, либо посредством `form.submit()`. При получении данных на сервере нужно проверить и со 100% точностью сказать, что данные были отправлены с клиента, а не посредством какой-нибудь библиотеки для отправки запросов. Пока что в голову пришла идея генерировать пару ключей - приватный и публичный. Оба генерировать на сервере при запросе страницы с формой. Публичный ключ отправлять клиенту в захэшированном виде и при получении данных с формы проверять совпадают ли хэши отправленного ключа  и полученного ключа и далее уже проверять публичный и приватный ключ. Но я в этом разбираюсь лишь поверхностно и не уверен туда ли я вообще копаю. Возможно, есть какие-нибудь другие способы?

Comment: Никак. Описанную вами схему тоже можно провернуть с использованием библиотеки.

Comment: @andreymal в CloudFlare каким-то образом эту проблему решили с помощью "задачи". Страница отдаёт форму и некий JS-код, который решает какую-то задачу и отправляет результат её решения в составе формы на сервер. Чтобы посмотреть исходные коды просто обратитесь к любой странице, которая выдаёт "Checking your browser before accessing...". Или, например, вот один из исходных кодов: https://pastebin.com/BwZWgCuD

Comment: Неправда, я успешно обхожу защиту Cloudflare в своих Python-ботах, просто подключив библиотеку для выполнения js-кода.

Comment: @andreymal да, я видел исходники cloudflare-scrape. Он загружает этот JS-код и выполняет его в NodeJS. Мне бы разобраться хотя бы что это за задача такая и как её решить, потому что на первый взгляд кажется что это какой-то обфусцированный мусор, но на деле там какие-то битмаски в виде `+!![]` и т.д. Я так полагаю, что они на сервере генерируют рандомное число, а затем хардкодят генерацию этого числа и заставляют клиента проводить вычисления, но я не уверен. Таким образом, форму нельзя будет отправить без необходимости исполнения JS-кода

Comment: Ну это уже немного другой вопрос, нежели описанный здесь. Этот метод всё равно не позволяет определить 100% клиента, потому что существует cloudflare-scrape :)

Comment: Кроме того, ничто не мешает взять библиотеку (есть и для python, и для js), которая просто управляет браузером — и тогда все подобные проверки автоматически пройдутся. С некоторой вероятностью пройдётся даже гугловская рекапча «Я не робот» (если гугл посчитает пользователя не слишком подозрительным) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsF7enQY8uI

Comment: @andreymal да, про puppeteer я тоже знаю :) В данном случае, моя задача - не допустить отправки формы с не-javascript-клиентов или заставить клиентов выполнять дополнительный код с целью уменьшения количества отправленных форм.

Comment: Тогда достаточно посчитать что-нибудь в духе `input.value = 2 + 2` и проверить на сервере что получилось 4. Те, кому лень, не обойдут и это, а кому не лень, всё равно любой Cloudflare обойдут